# Adding arrays to Hashmap<String,Object>?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a Hashmap that accepts strings and objects, I want to add a String[] and Object[] to the hashmap and it does not appear to add them as objects.

I have been out of the Java world for 11 years, so apologies if this is smashing a square peg into a round hole, I just expect when passing an object in the form of the arrays, that it would work.

I will add that the same code (obviously slightly different) works in C# passing the arrays into a Dictionary of String and Object, hence the expectation that it would be similar in Java.

I have tried to declare the arrays outside of the put command and that's as far as I have got testing.

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("sl", new String[]{"AZN"});
params.put("dType", "trade");
// year - the year minus 1900
// month - 0 to 11
params.put("startDate", new Date(2018-1900, 11, 20));
params.put("endDate", new Date(2018-1900, 11, 20));
params.put("tZ", "Eur");
params.put("ac", "equity");
params.put("af", new Object[]{"=", "price", 6031} );
```

I would expect that the params would have a string array called sl and an object array af with 3 entities... sl and af are currently blank

when I say its blank I see:

```
params[0] sl >
params[1] dType > trade
params[2] startDate > 2018-11-20
params[3] endDate > 2018-11-20
params[4] tZ > Eur
params[5] ac > equity
params[6] af >
```

As can be seen above this is the output I can see.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `params`. And please describe the actual error you are seeing.

Comment: This code should work, as far as I can see. Perhaps you could post a [mcve] that includes creating your hashmap, how you are trying to retrieve your arrays from your hashmap, and what exact results you are getting.

Comment: using a `Map<String, Object>` is probably the wrong approach, why not create your own `class` with the mentioned map-keys as fields. Then you would first have type safety and secondly already a clear documentation what your object holds. (no need for `map.containsKey("xxx")` anymore)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "`al` and `sf` are currently blank" (more specifically the "are...blank", part, not so much the "currently" part...)?

Comment: the ``` was on the declaration and as such the hashmap was not seen

Comment: What is the logic that prints the content of map in the format shown "params[0] sl >".

Comment: Its the debugger mode in Intelij once I breakpoint just after the final params.put, but before the call that uses params hashMap.

Comment: As Sl and af stores an array, you should select the > and in the drop down you can see the vales, no problem with code, the value is not blank (In intellij debug).

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code. But, as the params map stores Object as value, you might need to cast the value back to its type each time you get it from the map (each key stores a value whose type is different.).

```
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("sl", new String[]{"AZN"});
        params.put("dType", "trade");
// year - the year minus 1900
// month - 0 to 11
        params.put("startDate", new Date(2018-1900, 11, 20));
        params.put("endDate", new Date(2018-1900, 11, 20));
        params.put("tZ", "Eur");
        params.put("ac", "equity");
        params.put("af", new Object[]{"=", "price", 6031} );

        for(Object obj:(Object[]) params.get("af")) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

        for(String obj:(String[]) params.get("sl")) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays are being added to the Map successfully. I'm not sure how are you finding it to be blank. When I try below, I do see the value getting printed:

```
params.forEach((k, v)->{
      System.out.println("key: " + k + "\tvalue: " + v);
    });
```

Output:

```
key: ac value: equity
key: endDate    value: Thu Dec 20 00:00:00 IST 2018
key: af value: [Ljava.lang.Object;@119d7047 // Class name + hashcode of the object being printed
key: tZ value: Eur
key: dType  value: trade
key: sl value: [Ljava.lang.String;@776ec8df // Class name + hashcode of the object being printed
key: startDate  value: Thu Dec 20 00:00:00 IST 2018
```

Try below if you want to print array values:

```
params.forEach((k, v)->{
      if(v.getClass().isArray()) {
        v = Arrays.toString((Object[])v);
      }
      System.out.println("key: " + k + "\tvalue: " + v);
    });
```